# matching upto first character in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying regular expression

```
private void btnTip_Click\(object sender, EventArgs e\)(.*?\n)[^}]*
```

to match

```
    private void btnTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnTip.Visible = false;
        this.pnlTips.Visible = true;
        this.btnHide.Visible = true;
    }
```

but it is matching only till

```
    private void btnTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnTip.Visible = false;
        this.pnlTips.Visible = true;
        this.btnHide.Visible = true;
```

missing `}`

Need help .. i am novice in regex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just appended one extra `}` to your RegEx. Its working fine now.

```
private void btnTip_Click\(object sender, EventArgs e\)(.*?\n)[^}]*}
```

[Check-Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN5uN8/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
private void btnTip_Click\(object sender, EventArgs e\)(.*?\n)[^}]*\}
```

I just added the `\}` at the end. I can't test it here though so try it without the backslah if it doesn't work. In which environment are you using these regular expressions?